# Capture paste event in CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton

Tags: mfc, paste, mfc-feature-pack, cmfctoolbar

We have an MFC SDI application in VS2010 with a CMFCToolBar containing a `CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton`.  Is there a way to handle the paste event when a user pastes something into that edit box?

We handle `ON_COMMAND(ID_EDIT_PASTE, OnEditPaste)` in the main window but the paste message isn't getting raised when focus is inside the `CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the MFC Sources [afxtoolbareditboxbutton.cpp], it looks like the 'Paste()' function of the underlying `CMFCToolBarEditCtrl` is called directly during Ctrl-V, the 'Paste()' member function just sends `WM_PASTE` to the edit window.

Could do try making a handler for `WM_PASTE`?

[This SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2317077/1850797) has an example of how to do this.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring out how to attach a handler to the CEdit already created inside the CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton or subclassing the button to creates a different CEdit or where else WM_PASTE could be handled.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: You could override `CMFCToolBarEditBoxButton::CreateEdit()` [MFC Source afxtoolbareditboxbutton.cpp] and supply your own CEdit-derived class where you can handle the WM_PASTE?